# How much energy can one muscle contraction deliver?

Tags: muscles, energy

How much energy is available in a single muscle contraction?  I'm guessing the correct units are J/kg, but I'm open to more correct units.  I'm looking for work done, not total energy dissipated (not interested in heat)

The goal of such a number is to figure out an upper bound on how much work a human body can do if it is never permitted to reset a muscle by moving the limb in the opposite direction (If the bicep does work for this test, the triceps isn't permitted to contract to return the curled arm back to its initial straight position)

Comment: This question needs substantially editing to make it at all answerable ~ different muscles in a body are different sizes ~ the same muscle in different people are different sizes ~ the size of a muscle necessarily impacts on how much energy it can exert ~ so "one muscle" means almost anything in that sense.

Comment: @Pelinore That's why I said I believe the correct units will be J/kg, which resolves that issue.  However, I'm open to other units which are more correct for making such measurements.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.